# Moving an image in an canvas on page load

Tags: html, image, animation, canvas, kineticjs

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bbCE2/)

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    var yoda = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 200,
      y: 50,
      image: imageObj,
      width: 106,
      height: 118
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    layer.add(yoda);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);
  };
  imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg';

  var amplitude = 150;
  var period = 2000;
  // in ms
  var centerX = stage.getWidth() / 2;

  var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
    yoda.setX(amplitude * Math.sin(frame.time * 2 * Math.PI / period) + centerX);
  }, layer);

  anim.start();
```

How would I have the yoda image animate from left to right, say 50px, once on page load? Is it possible to do this with easing as well? Very new to canvas, thanks for any help. Would this be better suited to be left to jQuery instead?

Comment: You just need to reorder -- http://jsfiddle.net/bbCE2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at console you'll see that `yoda` is not defined. This is happening because `image.onload` is a function and variables created inside a function are visible only inside that function. So you need to create `yoda` outside a function.

Also start the animation only after the image is loaded.

[**Modified Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/ycVLp/)

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! Is there a way to have the image just move to the right once then stop?

Comment: @david: Yes, you can use `Kinetic.Tween` with linear easing. See [kinetic documentation](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Tween.html). If you find trouble with that, you can always ask another question. And remember to accept those answers that solve your problems. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @david: Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/xAHzg/) with linear easing tween as bonus. ;)